# How to set a parameter for class mediator?

Tags: class, wso2

I write a extending mediator class. I can only set value for the property. But I want to use a XPath expression. How I can do this?

The config like:

```
<class name="org.wso2.esb.tutorial.mediators.SurchargeStockQuoteMediator">
    <property name="defaultPercentage" value="10"/>
</class>
```

Answer (score 4):

I face the same problem, when I put value into property like this :

```
<property name="something" expression="get-property('value_of_something')"/>
```

ESB said value must be static or something..

So I use this solution :

1) I put value_of_something into any property

```
<property name="value_of_something" value="some value"/>
```

2) Then in my mediate() method in mediator class I get that **property** with name **value_of_something** from **MessageContext** object like this

```
 boolean mediate(MessageContext synCtx) {
       String value_of_something = synCtx.getProperty("value_of_something")+"";
 }
```